# Error term distribution and Homoscedasticity

Tags: error, heteroscedasticity, conditional-expectation

I have a very basic question.  In a linear regression model, we basically find the linear line by minimizing the error terms.  Then, due to check for the homoskedasticity visually, we plot independent variable vs random part.  And, we look for any change in variance of error term with respect to the independent variable.  It is ok.  But the thing is, in many books, the authors draws a distribution around the predicted-y, and check if the error term is inside that distribution.  I can't understand it!  Don't we have got only a single error term for every single data point of the independent variable?  If is it ok?, where does that distribution come from ?

[image: Here is the plot what i meant,]

Comment: Could you explain what you might mean by "every single independent variable"?  Presumably your photo depicts the observations in a bivariate dataset by means of point symbols.  It shows four distributions of those points located at four distinct values of "X", which is the *only* independent variable.

Comment: Thanks. I meant actually "for every single data point" of a one independent variable. And i made some search on google. I guess the answer of my question is related with the conditional variance. But i still  don't find a proper answer on google to ease my pain  :)